# async await in forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-2017

I have the following function that works as expected:

```
  createObjectFrom(record) {
    let obj = {};

    this.opts.transformers.forEach((transformer, index) => {
      const headerIndex = findIndex(this.headers, (header) => {
        return header === transformer.column;
      });

      const value = transformer.formatter(record[headerIndex]);

      obj[transformer.field] = value;
    });

    return obj;
  }
```

I want to refactor it to use async await and call an async function in the body of the forEach like this:

```
  createObjectFrom(record) {
    let obj = {};

    this.opts.transformers.forEach(async (transformer, index) => {
      const headerIndex = findIndex(this.headers, (header) => {
        return header === transformer.column;
      });

      const result = await this.knex('managers').select('name')

      console.log(result);

      const value = transformer.formatter(record[headerIndex]);

      obj[transformer.field] = value;
    });

    return obj;
  }
```

This will obviously break the function as the forEach is now executing asynchronously and the function will just execute and leave.

Is there a way I can use async await for the forEach to execute in a synchronous manner.  Could I refactor to generators?

Comment: "This will obviously break the function as the forEach is now executing asynchronously" --- it will not change anything. `Array.prototype.forEach` does not expect to accept `async` functions, so it will invoke it as a "normal" function. So all the functions will be called immediately.

Comment: "Is there a way I can use async await for the forEach to execute in a synchronous manner" --- just use a `for` or `for-of` loop to iterate over an array. You will also have to change `createObjectFrom` to be `async`.

Comment: You can this kind of stuff smoothly using [this one](https://github.com/toniov/p-iteration), give it a try if you don't mind using a module.

Answer (score 1):

You can not enforce a normal JS function to wait on async behavior. There is no way!

So you would have to refactor your `createObjectFrom` to be async as well. And then probably go for map/reduce instead of forEach.
To be performant you don't want to do this:

```
for(transformer of this.opts.transformers) {
    await this.knex('managers').select('name');
}
```

Instead you should use `await Promise.all(...)`.

However in your case the call to knex seems not to depend on the transformer, so you can do this:

```
async createObjectFrom(record) {
  let obj = {};

  const result = await this.knex('managers').select('name')

  this.opts.transformers.forEach(async (transformer, index) => {
    const headerIndex = findIndex(this.headers, (header) => {
      return header === transformer.column;
    });

    console.log(result);

    const value = transformer.formatter(record[headerIndex]);

    obj[transformer.field] = value;
  });

  return obj;
}
```

However if you want to do something like fetch for each item something async do it like this:

```
async foo(data) {
  const subDataArr = await Promise.all(data.map(record => loadSubData(record)));

  return subDataArr;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to need s knex call for each iteration of the foreach.  im curious how this is handled in node as it seems pretty common use case

Comment: @dagda1 thats basically my last code example. Assume `loadSubData` is the Knex call.